# SimpleJson foreach

Tags: c#, json

This is my json code:

[Json Code](http://pastebin.com/B6ShBEH8)

I use `SimpleJson` to deserialize it:

```
dynamic resp = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(response);
```

I get the link with

```
string link = resp["link"];
```

But now I want to get the value for each av in the `results` list?/array? !

I tried

```
foreach(dynamic item in resp["results"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

but this doesn't work (I get something like this:

[image: result]

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: What's *'correct'* from your point of view? *'Doesn't work'* is not a human-actionable description of a problem. At least not here on SO.

Comment: Where is the data in your screen shot coming from?

Comment: @SamLeach From `Console.WriteLine(item)` <- Code above!

Comment: @OndrejTucny I want to get the data in an array or something like that! I want an array (or something else) with the name of the av and the value (e.g. "Trojan.Win32.Packed.AH" from "Virit")!

Comment: For future reference, you're not likely to get any useful help with a question written this way. "Doesn't work" and "I want to get the data in an array or something like that" doesn't tell us how to help you. Explain the *exact* final result you want and be precise about where you're getting stuck trying to get there.

Comment: Your API must be written by someone named Jason, so to speak...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself!

```
foreach(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in resp["results"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("AV:{0} - Result {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That'll work, you could write it a little shorter if you wanted but you won't get any Intellisense on result because it's dynamic.

```
dynamic result = resp["results"];

foreach( var key in result.Keys )
{
    Console.WriteLine( key + " = " + result[key] );
}
```